# What's the difference between the name and the pathname of a service in Android's init.rc?

Tags: android, linux, bootstrapping

Under Android, in the file `/init.rc`, there is a line as follows:

```
service zygote /system/bin/app_process -Xzygote /system/bin ...
```

According to the [documentaion](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/master/init/readme.txt) on `init.rc`'s syntax, services should take the form of:

```
service <name> <pathname> [ <argument> ]*
   <option>
   <option>
   ...
```

Why is the service name different from the executable name of pathname?

Answer (score 0):

The service name is independent from it's executable because an executable can do different things based on it's arguments.

For example you could have 2 different services running the same executable but with different arguments.

NOTE: Take care that the service name is only allowed to be max. 16 characters long.